# RegExp object holding on to prior matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider this Javascript regular expression code:

```
v = 'The dog jumped over the moon';

// Matches
if (v.match(/(jump)ed/)) {
    alert('Initial: ' + RegExp.$1); // Alerts "jump"
}

// Obviously not matched, but RegExp object retains previous match
if (v.match(/(gygyujgujy)/)) {
    alert(RegExp.$1);
}

// Alerts "jump" but shouldn't this be null/false etc?
alert('Final: ' + RegExp.$1);
```

The second regular expression, despite not matching, holds on to the first regular expressions matches.

Shouldn't the RegExp object be empty because of the no match on the second regular expression?

Comment: I'd say, don't use RegExp like that; use it like this: `var match = v.match(/(jump)ed/); if(match){ console.log(match, match.index, match.input); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n

> "The $1, ..., $9 properties are static, they are not a property of an individual regular expression object. Instead, you always use them as RegExp.$1, ..., RegExp.$9.
>
> The values of these properties are read-only and modified whenever successful matches are made."

Since your 2nd if-statement never matches anything, no new value will be assigned to $1

Answer (score 0):

They are non-standard properties and [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n) as:

> The values of these properties are read-only and modified whenever *successful* matches are made.

There is no match for `gygyujgujy` so the existing value remains.